# Ready or pending future depending on a condition

Tags: rust, rust-futures

I need to save a ready or pending future in a variable depending on a condition.

Would be nice if I could do this:

```rust
let f = futures::future::ready(true);
```

But the API provides two different functions, which have different return types, so, this does not work either:

```rust
let f = if true { futures::future::ready(()) } else { futures::future::pending::<()>() }
```

I understand that I can implement my own future for this, but I wonder if there is a way to make the `if` expression work?

Comment: This future you want should be always either ready or pending?

Comment: Sure, there's [`futures::future::Either`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/future/enum.Either.html).

Comment: @SvenMarnach, Thank you! That is exactly what I was searching for.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`futures::future::Either`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/future/enum.Either.html) type:

```
use futures::future::Either;
use std::future::{pending, ready, Future};

pub fn pending_or_ready(cond: bool) -> impl Future<Output = ()> {
    if cond {
        Either::Left(ready(()))
    } else {
        Either::Right(pending())
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ab1e5e8c1616833f58ac69ae418647fb))